# Diplaying a list of object data on an HTML page

Tags: jquery, html

I've been working on a web application that requires the user to input certain request data. Once this data has been captured it will be displayed in the form of a grid with only the main content of the data displayed while the rest of the content will only be displayed once the user clicks on the main content. At the moment i'm displaying the data as a JQuery accordion as below:

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2449/requestlist1.jpg](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2449/requestlist1.jpg)

I somehow feel that displaying a list of data using an Accordion is a bit cluttered. Any nice ideas?

Comment: I can't seem to get the picture display. How can I do this? Its stored on my local drive.

Comment: upload to image to a site, then add as image.

Comment: facepalm - I would hope for your sake that the internet cannot read your local drive ;)

Comment: you can't link to an image in your computer. Think about it for a second and it should make sense. Upload it to a hosting provider or an image service and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is one appropriate way to show table data.
It's a matter of your target audience.

If you want to show lots of items with fast access to details accordion might be the right solution. If there is a lot of details, then you might consider going for a Master -> Details.

Another way might be to implement a modal popup [example](http://www.ajaxline.com/master-detail-with-the-gridview-details-view-and-jquery-s-thickbox)

Anyways you can find more inspiration here:  [jquery grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations) or  [RadGrid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/groupby/grouploadmodeclient/defaultcs.aspx).

Try different colors, font-sizes, more contrast between the stuff that matters to your users and the details/effects/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. The below, collapsed data is related to the above? Is it a parent-child relationship or how do they belong to each other? If yes, you are looking for some kind of drill down, if not, the accordion is totally fine.

By the way, using jpegs for screenshots often sucks, you should take png or something (reminds me of [this](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/))